# How to read Excel file which has Excel formulae to calculate the values via PySpark lib com.crealytics.spark.excel

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Excel file like :[image]

It has Calculated columns using excel formuale for every value

I have tried to read this file using:

```
input_MonthGroup_df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .option('inferSchema','true')\
    .load(MonthGroup_file_path)
```

The O/P is wrong :[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to read a formulated Excel file:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, DateType

df = pd.read_excel(<filePath>, engine="openpyxl")
schema = StructType([StructField("Month", DateType(), True), StructField("12 Month Lookback", DateType(), True)])
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df, schema=schema)
sdf.show()
```

This will read the file as it is shown below:

[image]

Comment: Pandas is not allowed in our Org. Can you suggest using com.crealytics.spark.excel

Comment: can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/azure/articles/75615365/azure-synapse-analytics-how-to-read-an-excel-data-from-adls-gen2-and-write-syna) once?

Comment: I have installed required jar and am able to read normal excel.But The question is am not able to read a excel which has formulae in it. as Shown 12 Month Look back Column is formulated / Manupulated.

Comment: Can you check [this](https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/spark-read-excel-with-formula/td-p/31948) once.

Comment: I have read the entire post , there is no such solution discussed but at the last comment ,it says "Spark doesnot interpret Excel formulae." Only it can replace Error Cells according column dtype using setErrorCellsToFallBackValues. So ,if its not there yet in excel lib ,then we need to wait until it gets added to that lib.